# Conda: подключение окружений из другой установки на другом диске

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Как подключить существующие окружения (environment) из установки conda на другом диске с другой ОС? И будут ли активироваться обычной командой "activate env_name"?
Имеется Windows 7, хочется использовать с дисков с Windows 10, и с Linux Ubuntu.

Со связкой Linux-Windows конечно сомнения, ибо форматы файлов разные, не запустятся. Тогда можно ли сделать соответствующую копию?